# Can I suppress the log message in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, internet-explorer-9, console.log

Web apps running in Google Apps Script in the EMULATED sandbox mode seem to always log out this message: `Running in Sandbox mode: EMULATED`.

IE9 has a problem where if you call `console.log()`, Javascript will stop executing because the `console` object is undefined until you open devTools.

Normally, one can either simply *not call* console.log, or use a shim like this to avoid this issue:

`if(!window.console){window.console={log:function(){},error:function(){}}}`

Using a shim like above does not amend my problem (I'm presuming because the Google Apps Script initializes the sandbox and logs the message *before* sending my page and JS).  I know that IE9 is not officially supported by Google but this is what people in my company primarily use.  Is there any way to suppress this message, or otherwise get javascript to work on my page?

Comment: May be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/266509/greasemonkey-for-ie-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978736/how-to-run-greasemonkey-script-before-the-page-content-is-displayed

Comment: So you cant use the (usually better) iframe mode?

Comment: @ZigMandel Doesn't IE9 throws back at EMULATED? From the documentatio `This mode imposes many fewer restrictions than the other sandbox modes and runs fastest, but **does not work at all in certain older browsers, including Internet Explorer 9**.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like this wasn't apps script's fault, because my app is working now.  I rewrote and republished the page to get rid of jQuery for speed, and it started working.  Not sure what the issue really was.  In any case it is resolved.