# JavaScript: reset all event handlers to defaults / disable custom handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to somehow reset all the event handlers / listeners, attached in course of execution of JavaScript code on the page to their default values, i.e. disabling all the custom functionality, as if the page was loaded without JavaScript support?

I know that I can, for example, reset handlers on individual elements with JQuery's `$(selector).off()`, but when yet another "clever" site overrides right click, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+arrows or anything like that and I just want to turn it all off — sometimes I'm not very inclined to dig through their code to find out what they've attached it to, and would love a simpler, one-size-fits-all solution. Is there one?

UPDATE: Found similar question
[Remove All Event Listeners of Specific Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/javascript-remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type) — where an accepted answer states that it's impossible for a specific event type. Is it still true as of 2016?

Comment: i think thats hard, you can use "*" as selector... but then you still have all the other events, which are not attached to an object... or is window included in "*"? keep trying!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want try this?

`$("*").unbind();`

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_unbind.asp

Comment: Only works on handlers attached by jQuery. If someone uses `.addEventListener` directly, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, and, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work on `onXXX` handlers either.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be possible (but I haven't tried):

Make a GreaseMonkey script or browser extension that [executes at document start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978736/how-to-run-greasemonkey-script-before-the-page-content-is-displayed) (similarly for browser extensions).
It should redefine `EventTarget.addEventListener` to add the event name, target and handler to an array, then invoke the original function.
You can then iterate over the array and `removeEventListener` all of them at will. Alternately, for a more aggressive approach, you could redefine `EventTarget.addEventListener` to be a no-op.

This does not solve any handlers declared as `onXXXXX` fields; you would need to [seek and destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085316/disable-all-javascript-events-on-page) those manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unbind a specific event, like a click, try and iterate through all the children of the body element, like this:

```
$('body').children().off('click');
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martiensk/1ghLn9x2/).

If you need to unbind multiple different events, try creating a function and passing it an array of events to unbind.

Comment: Check out Lin Yuan's answer for a better solution.